# Inconveniente al crear aplicación en Django de usuarios registrados que puedan iniciar sesión y acceder a información de la base de datos principal

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

Estoy tratando de crear una aplicación en Django donde los usuarios registrados puedan iniciar sesión y acceder a cierta información de la base de datos principal, pero no puedo hacer el filtro con queryset en Django cuando el usuario inicia sesión, y en la página de bienvenida muestran la informacion de todos los usuarios u no la de ese usuario especifico.. para explicarme mejor cuando cree el modelo de mi aplicacion en la parte de administracion de Django hay un modelo llamado "users" que es la informacion de los usuarios logeados, como podria enlazar el ID del usuario logeado con mi base de datos creada en el archivo "models".

Comment: podrias agregar el codgio con lo que has intentado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La aplicación de autentificación de usuarios de Django (django.contrib.auth) proporciona decoradores y mixins para limitar el acceso a determinadas vistas.

Usando esos decoradores (si defines vistas a través de funciones) o mixins (si defines las vistas mediante clases), puedes limitar el acceso al contenido a usuarios registrados, a usuarios con determinados permisos, etc.

### Ejemplos:

#### Limitar el acceso a la página de login a los usuarios que no estén identificados:

```
class CustomLoginView(UserPassesTestMixin, LoginView):
    authentication_form = LoginForm
    form_class = LoginForm
    template_name = 'accounts/login.html'

    def test_func(self):
        return not self.request.user.is_authenticated

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('accounts:view', kwargs={'username': self.request.user.username})
```

#### Limitar el acceso a la lista de todos los usuarios a los usuarios que estén identificados y sean superusuarios

```
class AccountIndexView(LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Account
    queryset = Account.objects.filter(user__is_active=True).all()
    permission_required = 'auth.view_user'
    paginate_by = 10
    template_name_suffix = '_index'
    login_url = 'login'
```

Estos dos ejemplos utilizan los mixins porque son vistas definidas utilizando clases.

Cuando se usa el decorador, se escribe de esta forma:

```
@login_required
def mi_vista(request):
    …
```

La documentación oficial está disponible solo en inglés, pero es clara:

- [The login_required decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator)
- [The LoginRequiredMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin)

Espero que te sea de ayuda.